# ElasticSearch sort by id's in array

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

Is there a way to sort some elasticsearch response in the same direction, which I am posting an array with ids?

Example: array[23,45,67] and the results should be sort in the same way like the id's are: first come all rows with ID 23, after that all rows with ID 45 and at the end all rows with ID 67 ?

Thanks
Nik

Comment: Can you show a few sample documents and the query you'd like to send (even if not conform)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scripting in sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting) or the other option is to use bool - should query where you boost documents with these values.